# Detailed documentation of pydanny's cookiecutter?

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I tried using [it](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) but instead of kick-starting me it only caused a lot of confusions. Is there a book or article somewhere that explains what every single file that cookiecutter generates does? I mean there's a documentation but it does not really help.

Feel free to delete if this does not belong here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check "Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices for Django".